# How to replace NA values in R depending on the value of another column?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following problem:

As an example I have this dataframe

```
> employee <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope')
> salary <- c(NA, NA, NA)
> startdate <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2008-3-25','2007-3-14'))
> employ.data <- data.frame(employee, salary, startdate)
```

And I defined this list

```
> l <- list("John Doe" = "23400", 
               "Peter Gynn" = "28000",
               "Jolie Hoper" = "34000")
```

Now, I'm trying to replace the NA values in the salary column based on the value of the employee column and using the list. Is there a fast way to do it with dplyr? I'm looking for something different to case when because I have a lot of key values in the list... Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this with `dplyr` as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
employ.data %>%
    mutate(
        salary = unlist(ifelse(is.na(salary) & employee %in% names(l), l[employee], salary))
    )
```

Comment: Hi! It works, but now I have another problem. It transforms the colum into a list and I can't export the dataframe in csv. I'm trying this:

`write_excel_csv(employ.data, "out/csv/data.csv")`

Comment: Hi Razvan, this didn't seem to happen in the small example, or I didn't see it happen.. Would wrapping the `ifelse(...)` in an `unlist` call solve the problem for you or does that throw an error?

Comment: Might need `use.names=F`. So: `unlist(fields(...), use.names=F)`

Comment: Thank you so much! It works wrapping the call to `l[employee]` in the `unlist` as follows:

`library(dplyr)
employ.data %>%
mutate(salary = ifelse(is.na(salary), unlist(l[employee], use.names=F), salary))`

Comment: Actually, `unlist` sneaks in a dangerous error! Using your above line, the nonexistent "Jolie Hope" will be assigned a salary, which is false!! I've yet adapted my above answer to catch that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `merge`:

```
#1. Convert your list to data.frame

    salaries <- data.frame(employee = names(l), salary = unlist(l))

#2. Merge `salaries` with `employ.data`

    merge(salaries, employ.data,  by = "employee", all = TRUE)[-3]
        employee salary.x  startdate
    1   John Doe    23400 2010-11-01
    2 Jolie Hope    34000 2007-03-14
    3 Peter Gynn    28000 2008-03-25
```

Note that in my example there's only `Jolie Hope`, you also have `Jolie Hoper`  I don't know if this is a typo. Nevertheless this solution will also work if `Jolie Hoper` is in your list.

Answer (score 0):

We can use join `on` with `data.table` after `stack`ing the named `list` to a two column data.frame

```
library(data.table)
setDT(employ.data)[stack(l), salary := values, on = .(employee = ind)]
employ.data
#     employee salary  startdate
#1:   John Doe  23400 2010-11-01
#2: Peter Gynn  28000 2008-03-25
#3: Jolie Hope  34000 2007-03-14
```

---

Or in `base R` with simple subsetting based on the names

```
employ.data$salary <-  with(employ.data, unlist(l[employee]))
```

#### data

```
l <- list("John Doe" = 23400, 
           "Peter Gynn" = 28000,
           "Jolie Hope" = 34000)
employee <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope')
salary <-  rep(NA_real_, 3)
startdate <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2008-3-25','2007-3-14'))
employ.data <- data.frame(employee, salary, startdate)
```